# SQL MAX function

Tags: teradata

Suppose I have a table with attributes Name, Age as follows:

```
MyTable (Name, Age)
```

Now, to get the oldest age I can write the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(Age) AS "Oldest Age" FROM MyTable;
```

However, I cannot figure out the query in the case when I only want the name of the person with the oldest age. I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
SELECT Name FROM MyTable
WHERE MAX(Age);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Teradata Web SQL Assistant. If two names have the same max age, show both.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Teradata supports window functions, so you can use them to pick the larges value.

```
select name, age
from (
   select name, age, 
          dense_rank() over (order by age desc) as rn
   from MyTable
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If there are multiple names with the same age, all would be shown. If you only want to pick one, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

Using window functions is very often faster than sub-selects.

Answer (score 1):

There could be more than one names that share the same maximum age. To find them all, you can use the fairly standard SQL statement, which should work in almost all DBMS:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM MyTable) ;
```

Only in some DBMS, like SQL-Server (and Teardata I think), you could use this as well:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES Name 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Age DESC ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause needs a condition, if you type:

```
SELECT Name FROM MyTable
WHERE MAX(Age);
```

there is no condition. Try to translate it to a sentence:

> Select the name from MyTable where maximum age...

Now compare it with this statement:

> Select the name from MyTable where the age field is equals to (select the maximum age)

And now in SQL code:

```
SELECT Name FROM MyTable
WHERE Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM MyTable);
```

Hope it helped.